# Python installation on aix

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, installation, aix

Is it possible to install Python on AIX server. I have installed it on Linux and Windows but not able to find the correct installables for AIX

Comment: ActiveState appear to sell AIX builds of ActivePython. Not sure which versions though. http://www.activestate.com/business-edition

Comment: Do you have any problem with compiling this from source? It is not that difficult.

Answer (score 1):

A few choices.  As Anthon says, you could try compiling it yourself.

Another choice is http://www.perzl.org/aix/  I see a 2.6 build there.

Answer (score 1):

You can find official python RPM's for AIX [here](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html%20%22here%22.)

Answer (score 1):

Check the AIX package at https://github.com/chevah/python-package/releases. This includes OpenSSL 1.0.2 libraries, patched with the latest security updates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install yum from [here](http://ftp.software.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/ezinstall/ppc/yum_bundle.tar)
Untar it and install all rpms. I will auto install python 2.7, after you can install python3 from yum.